# How to run cut command in vim and change the current file

Tags: linux, vim, cut

How do I run [cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) command inside vim and change the contents of the file being edited. I tried following but did not work.

```
:r ! cut -d ":" -f 1 % > %
```

and some other variants of it. I want to edit the currently open file using cut and want to know how to accomplish this using only cut inside vim itself.

Comment: Why don't you use vim feature to do the same work?  Is there any particular reason for invoking cut?

Comment: 's' substitute command in vi is really powerful

Comment: @dlmeetei as I said, I wanted to know how to accomplish this using cut inside vim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because the redirection operator `>` makes the shell truncate the file *before* the command is executed, so `cut` sees an empty input file.

You could instead use [`:w`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#writing) to pipe the contents of the current buffer to `cut` via stdin, then redirect to the file:

```
:w ! cut -d ":" -f 1 > %
```

This has a side effect of Vim prompting you to reload the file. You can use alternatives that don't exhibit this behaviour, such as a [substitution](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute):

```
:%s/:.*//
```

or a [filter](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#filter) command:

```
:% ! cut -d ":" -f 1
```

Comment: Using filter, `!`, is the easiest and simplest method

Answer (score 3):

```
:%!cut -d":" -f1
```

see `:help :range!`

Comment: Thanks, this works, can you please add an explantion as well so this answer becomes more useful and complete.